# knowrob error

Tags: knowrob

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi

I tried to run the knowrob visualisation with visualisation_canvas(C). but got the error:  syntax error near unexpected token `C'. Any help¿

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/41422/knowrob---error/) by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on ROS Answers with karma: 330 on 2012-08-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-08-15**:
Please always add the tag 'knowrob' for knowrob related questions to make sure the right people get notified.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I had the same error once... are you on ROS Electric? Just updating KnowRob to the latest svn ( http://code.in.tum.de/pubsvn/knowrob/tags/latest ) solved it and in Fuerte it works fine for me.

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-08-15

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Astronaut](https://answers.ros.org/users/2221/astronaut/) on 2012-08-15**:
No. Im on Fuerte, But solved the problem. Anyway thanks., But I have some problems with the semantic map. I want to use my occupancy map of the environment and yaml file for owl. But don not know how to use that information to create semantic map. Any help or tutorial about it?

**Comment by [Lorenz](https://answers.ros.org/users/21/lorenz/) on 2012-08-15**:
As already answered in your other question, semantic maps cannot be directly generated from an occupancy grid. There's just no semantic information in there. You will have to invest some work to understand the basics and create your semantic map manually.

**Comment by [HiroCollins](https://answers.ros.org/users/6334/hirocollins/) on 2013-09-04**:
Astronaut, how did you solve the problem? I get the lights() is not available with this renderer error. I am using ros fuerte and the svn knowrob. Thanks in advance.

**Comment by [moritz](https://answers.ros.org/users/214/moritz/) on 2013-09-04**:
The 'lights()' warning is no error and should not be a problem. If the visualization does not start, please open a question and list both the commands you enter and the results you get.

**Comment by [HiroCollins](https://answers.ros.org/users/6334/hirocollins/) on 2013-09-04**:
ok I will do as you suggested.